# Using sqlldr with " in strings

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, sql-loader

So I have a text file with lots of data I want to load into plsql.

I have successfully completed this task using a batch file for the majority of the text file, but names with a " in the name threw up an error.

For example, some names are things like Sally"s Bakery instead of Sally's Bakery.

I get an error:

> no terminator found after TERMINATED and ENCLOSED field

Does anyone know a way to get around it?

Comment: What does your control file look like?  Are you using the double quote character as an optional enclosure?  Or a field separator?  An optional enclosure character shouldn't exist in the underlying data.

Comment: Yeah it's comma delimited and optionally enclosed with "
When I look at the error log, lots of the records that didn't load have either ""Mr", "John", "Smith" 
"Sally", "O"Connor" 
or some other silly errors like that. Is there any quick fix to remove the extra "'s inside the original "x"?

Comment: You'd want your optional enclosure character to be something that doesn't occur in your data.  If you have a double-quote character in your data, your optional enclosure character should be something else.